# How to perform refresh all in excel through vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import records from a oracle database to an excel sheet by using the options "From Other sources" in the "Data" Tab.  I need a vba code to open the excel file from a specific location and then press "Refresh All" Button.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the data in a workbook, you can use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Why do you need to open the excel file from a specific location? If the connection is stored in the workbook, you shouldn't need to.

Comment: am able to do fresh all with this, but am not able to save when i do activeworkbook.close savchanges:=True

Comment: What do you mean not able to save? Is there an error?